# What does the title of the anime "K" mean?

Tags: k-project

In 2012, there was [an anime titled **K**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_%28anime%29) (or sometimes **K Project**). Does the title mean anything in the context of the anime?

(cf. [**C**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28anime%29), which was titled for the word "Control", and [**X**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_%28manga%29), which was supposedly titled after the use of the letter "x" as a variable).

Comment: I would say it stands for "Kings".

Comment: I would say it is for King

Answer (score 5):

There are two possibilities for what the "K" refers to.

The first is Adolf K. Weismann, who is the original person that became Yashiro Isana, the main character of the show.

The second is "King". The leader of each clan is its King, who controls the members of the clan.  Weismann is a King.

KINGS is also the first opening theme of the show.

Comment: J/C, any reason for the quote block there? Doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @Eric It was an accident, which I have now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put together @poop's and @kuwaly's answers.

The two possibilities are are "K" for "King" or for Adolf "K" Weismann. However, the second for Weismann is incorrect. Wiki: http://k-project.wikia.com/wiki/Yashiro_Isana

After a bit of research as well as a search through the K-Project wiki, I found that Adolf's middle name isn't actually revealed in either the anime or any sources. Due to his middle name not being known, we can see that it is of little importance to the anime.

Now let's jump to the title of the last episode title, "King." We can piece the title of the anime together with the title of the final episode as the anime was leading up to the final episode, uniquely named, "King." "King," is the most likely of the two options since the plot line, use of the word "King" and the name of the final episode all relate to the one word, "King."

So the title of the anime would be, "King-Project," or "King."

Answer (score 0):

The K in K project stands for **König** which is aprecciated to be engraved on the slate. This is for König project, the main project carried in the second war by Adolf K Weismann which translated into english is King project.

Answer (score -1):

I've watched a talkshow. In that talkshow, the creator told that K means "Kizuna" or bonds. So, it means every character has a complex bond that bind 'em each other.

Comment: Do you maybe have a source? Like the actual talk show, maybe a transcript or such. Without the actual source to cite, this answer is of a very low quality.